# Recoding the memset in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C . I try to recode the memset. My friend helped me in the code.

```
void *
ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t n)
{
    unsigned char *str;

    str = (unsigned char *) b;
    while (n--)
        *str++ = (unsigned char) c;

    return (b);
}
```

I have severals question about this code.

1. why the `str = (unsigned char*)b` can't be   `str = unsigned char*b`  ?
2. When we declare `str = (unsigned char*)b` . Is the Str is receiving the same memory address of `* B` ?

Advance Thanks,

Comment: `unsigned char*b` is a syntax error.  The parentheses in `(unsigned char *)b` are just part of the syntax for the [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast).

Comment: Keep in mind that the `*` here is not multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, please try to do [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users); in this case, it's difficult if you don't already know the fundamentals, but you are supposed to learn the fundamentals by e.g. following a tutorial. Also please read [ask] and try to give your question a title that reflects the *problem you are asking about*, not simply the task that your code is performing.

Comment: One question is purposeless because it's a syntax error.  The other is purposeless because two minutes with a debugger would help you learn how the memory is affected by this code.

Comment: @TomServo: (a) The fact that something is a syntax error does not mean there is not a reason for that. Syntax is not entirely arbitrary; it must disambiguate, among other things. In this case, if a cast did not require parentheses, then `unsigned char * x` could be either a declaration of `x` to be an `unsigned char *` or a conversion of `x` to `unsigned char *`. So we need parentheses (or something else) to disambiguate the grammar. Thus, the question is not purposeless; there is an explanation. (b) Students at this level may not have been introduced to debuggers.

Comment: Since you say you are a beginner, I strongly recommend to teach yourself to write `return b;` instead of `return (b);`. The `return` keywords is special and is not a function. The braces do no harm, but they also don't help.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Anyone not using a debugger is wasting time and energy. To argue otherwise is pointless.  Re: disambiguation: C in particular is notoriously flexible, requiring any student of it to know precedence and cast rules to succeed. Again, a debugger and inspecting the conferred type would show that the compiler is not doing what is intended. In my opinion (and we all have one) the rich and free tools available today make questions about such things appear poorly researched.

Comment: @TomServo: I did not argue tgat OP would not benefit from using a debugger, so your statement about that is irrelevant. Nor did I argue that OP would not benefit from knowing C’s grammar rules. Rather, I disputed that the question was purposeless. Discussion of why the grammar rules are the way they are is rare, st least in this regard, so asking the question has the purpose of soliciting an answer. I challenge you to find elsewhere any explanation of why parentheses are required for a cast.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My main C book by Deitel & Deitel treats this topic in some detail.    Recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the str = `(unsigned char*)b` can't be `str = unsigned char*b` ?

Because `(unsigned char*)` is a cast. The second one is invalid syntax.

> When we declare str = (unsigned char*)b . Is the Str is receiving the
> same memory address of * B ?

It is not a declaration only assignment. `b` is the `void` pointer and we need to fill memory with the `unsignd char` value. So we assign the same reference to the pointer to `unsigned char`.